# How to debug change in key binding / command behavior (<c-p> / ctrl-p for ctrlp.vim vim plugin)?

Tags: vim, key-bindings, vim-plugin, ctrlp

I'm using the vim `ctrlp` plugin, and the `<c-p>` (`Ctrl+p`) key binding / command (which invokes `:CtrlP`) often goes back to the vim default of moving the cursor up a line.  I can't figure out why this is happening.  How can I debug this?

(I've been using the vim ctrlp plugin (https://github.com/ctrlpvim) for 5+ years, and this just started happening in the last month.  I've updated the bundle to the latest code from 25 May 2020.)

I thought maybe the mapping was getting lost, but before and after this behavior, the mappings are the same:

```
:filter /ctrlp/ map
   <C-P>         <Plug>(ctrlp)
n  <Plug>(ctrlp) * :<C-U>CtrlP<CR>
```

And when it happens, I can still use `:CtrlP` to get the same functionality as the `<c-p>` / `Ctrl+p` command that is no longer working.
If I exit vim and start vim again, it works again.

Workarounds:

- use `:CtrlP`
- use `Shift+Ctrl+p`
- restart `vim`

  ```
   $ vim --version
   VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Aug 20 2020 22:44:15)
  ```

Update (31 Aug 2020):

It looks like this might be either a `vim` issue or an `iTerm2` issue: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an [iTerm2 issue.](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9110) I'm gone from iTerm2 `Build 3.4.0beta4` to `Build 3.4.0beta10` and have not been seeing the issue anymore.

See also [this related vim issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6794).